# How to clean project in Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Whenever I try to **clean** my project, Build -> Clean Project,  in Android Studio 2.1, it executes the following command. Here's the output of Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.678 secs
```

Now I only want to **clean the project**, *not to rebuild it*. I've found one solution to do this by going into the **Gradle Window** and selecting **clean** manually but is there a better solution to do this because my solution feels like a hack. 
[Gradle Window Clean app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA2TH.png) And do you have any idea, *why is Android Studio behaving like this*?

Comment: i think the adb clear-debug-app  command will do it

Comment: `clean` manually is not a hacky but usual way.  or you can type to your usual console not only android studio gradle window.

Comment: yeah, but isn't clean just supposed to "Clean" the project and not build it again. I can execute the "Build" command when I want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal way Android studio clean projects. First they clean the project it has mentioned on the top of the Gradle Build message.

:clean
:app:clean

Comment: yeah, but isn't clean just supposed to "Clean" the project and not build it again. I can execute the "Build" command when I want to do so.